# How to create multiple buttons that do the same on different positions without creating actual new buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im really new to java and Programming as a whole. In school, I decided to work on a project to raise my grade, and as simple java is currently our topic i decided on trying to recreate battleships in a jframe using swing. I've made some good progress so far but im stuck on a quality of Life Problem.

So basically, in the editor we use (Java Editor ( javaeditor.org )) i use swing to implement buttons etc. in the jframe. As im gonna need a lot of Buttons for the games gui, I want to do it, so i dont have to make several buttons which have to be filled in with the arguments. What im trying to do is have some arguments create several buttons for me so they dont actually all need their own “method“ as all buttons have to basically do the exact same thing.

I tried searching for similar things on google but I couldnt find anything, so i decided to create this account to ask if someone might be able to help me with this Problem. If something isnt understandable feel free to ask (English isnt my mother tongue so some parts might be hard to understand).

Looking forward to any replies! Thanks in advance for helping.

Initially I thought I could use a for-loop to create these multiple buttons but there would always be some kind of error with the ActionPerformed argument.

```
for (int i = 0;i > 25;i++ ) {
      jButton[i].setBounds(48, 48 + i, 113, 73);
      jButton[i].setText("jButton1");
      jButton[i].setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
      jButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
          jButton[i]_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
      cp.add(jButton[i]);  
    }
```

As already said I expect there to be more than 1 button, whilst keeping the lines of code in the constructor as short as possible.

Comment: without creating another button, this is impossible. Else: ``jButton[i] = new JButton();``

Comment: Just use a for loop to create all the buttons. Or create them in a method. There are many ways to do this. Show us your best attempt.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter mentions two good approaches. My immediate thought was a factory method. Also, it is likely the game should have a model that is used by the view (the buttons in this case) to (re)configure themselves according to the current state of the game.

Answer (score 1):

If you're desiring a grid of buttons, then create them in a for loop, and place them in the JPanel using a GridLayout. Something like this might work:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ManyButtons extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDES = 10;
    private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[SIDES][SIDES];

    public ManyButtons() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));
        for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
                String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", col + 1, row + 1);
                buttonGrid[row][col] = new JButton(text);
                buttonGrid[row][col].addActionListener(event -> {
                    String command = event.getActionCommand();
                    System.out.println("Button pressed: " + command);
                });
                add(buttonGrid[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ManyButtons mainPanel = new ManyButtons();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Many Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also avoid `setBounds` and null layouts.

Regarding:

> .... without creating new JButtons

This is not technically possible if you want a fully functioning button (as opposed to creating a rendered button in a JTable), *however*, buttons can share ActionListeners, so all buttons that do the same kind of thing (think -- all the number buttons on a calculator) can use the very same ActionListener. Alternatively, you can set a button's Action using your own class that extends from AbstractAction for even greater flexibility and power, and multiple buttons (and JMenuItems) can share the same action.

Comment: Well that was a plus one from the start, then we get to *"Also avoid `setBounds` and null layouts."* Plus ten (borderline 11).

Comment: *"all the number buttons on a calculator) can use the very same ActionListener."* True. This [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556) was able to take it even further and simply did different things in the listener relevant to the action (there were only two other logical actions besides numbers, for `C` and `=`).